# How to define the PUT method in routing only limit to the Put methods in controller without parameter?

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Here is the routing configuration in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApiPut",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
    defaults: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Put) }
);


config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get, HttpMethod.Post, HttpMethod.Delete) }
);
```

Here is my controller:

```
public class MyController : ApiController {
    [HttpPut]
    public void Put()
    {
        //blah
    }
}
```

Somehow when the client sents the PUT request with the URL `/api/myController/12345`, it still maps to the `Put` method in `MyController`, I am expecting an error like resource not found.

How to force the `Put` method only accept the request without a parameter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're putting your `httpMethod` constraint into `defaults`, but it should be in `constraints`.

`defaults` just says what the default values will be if the request doesn't include some or all of them as routing parameters (which in the case of the verb, is meaningless, since every HTTP request always has a verb as part of the protocol). `constraints` limit the combination of route values that will activate the route, which is what you're actually trying to do.

FYI, for this simple/standard routing, you don't need the `[HttpPut]` attribute in an API controller either. That's already handled by the HTTP routing which maps the verb to the controller method.

Answer (score 10):

This works to constrain http method on routes:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "LocationApiPOST",
       routeTemplate: "api/{orgname}/{fleetname}/vehicle/location",
       defaults: new { controller = "location" }
       constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) }
   );

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "LocationApiGET",
       routeTemplate: "api/{orgname}/{fleetname}/{vehiclename}/location/{start}",
       defaults: new { controller = "location", start = RouteParameter.Optional }
       constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }
   );

   ...

}
```

Comment: This code sample worked for me except that I had to specify constraints as shown in the question, i.e.:   constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Get) }

Comment: There are two HttpMethodConstraint classes in .net 4.5.1.  One in System.Web.Routing and the other in System.Web.Http.Routing.  They require different parameter patterns, one accepts strings, the other looks for the enum.  I don't know yet if they have different behaviors beyond that.

Comment: @Rozwel  thanks!  I was banging my head a little getting the cannot convert to string error because I was using system.web.routing not system.web.http.routing.